# Poor image quality after downloading from android asset

Tags: android, android-assets, image-resolution

I'm trying to get an image to fit nicely on each screen size, the image i'm using an image which is 1351 × 2048 and i have used android asset to achieve this. It has worked fine except from the image quality is a lot more poor on all resolution. Images are too large to add to here to show difference.

Comment: Did you try an library? Like Picasso or Glide.

Comment: @JorgeManuelBello Thanks for the reply, but yes i have and with no luck :(

Comment: Ok, are you sure when uploading that image it doesn't make any compression or when downloading?, try downloading using another tool

Comment: Yeh, the compression was the issue here. Downloading from google asset compresses them hence why it loses quality, i'm going to adjust the sizing in photoshop and add them to the correct folder. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed it, the way around this is to find the correct sizes for each resolution and change this in photoshop to avoid losing quality, then add the correct size to each folder hdpi - xxxhdpi, for some reason the image will lose quality when compressing folders which is what android asset does.